# Positionning div with JS

Tags: javascript, height

Quick explanation :

I have a page split into two columns. (using div style="float:left; width:50%;).
Some elements (span) on the left column have an ID. Then, on the right column, some other elements have also their own ID.

Now i'm using JS to position the height of an element of column A at the same height of an element of column B.
Here's what I used :

```
document.getElementById(spanInA).style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById(spanInA).style.top = heightOfSpanInB.toString() + "px";
```

So far, it was working fine however I have a problem : when the element (left column) is too long, its text will overlap on the column on the right.

Someone here suggested me to add a div like this :

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<span id="".$id."">".$text."</span>
</div>
```

But that doesn't solve the problem, the texts will be indeed wrapped but they are all below the bottom of the text in the column B.

Last thing i tried is to replace spans by divs, (so it's just div id="..">text /div>) but it's just the same result as initially with spans only.

halp plox
ty !

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the height of the element using one of this functions:

```
var heightOfSpanInB = document.getElementById("spanInA").clientHeight;
var heightOfSpanInB = document.getElementById("spanInA").offsetHeight;
```